# MergeError using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=["x","y","z"])
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"x":[1],"y":[2]}, index=["foo"])
```

I'm trying to get this result:

```
       z  x  y
foo  NaN  1  2
```

I tried

```
df1.merge(df2,how="outer", on=["x","y"], right_index=True)
```

which gives the error

```
MergeError: Can only pass argument "on" OR "left_index" and "right_index", not a combination of both.
```

However, neither

```
df1.merge(df2,how="outer", on=["x","y"])
```

nor

```
df1.merge(df2,how="outer", left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

give the desired result...

Comment: Your first empty DataFrame is fairly pointless. I think you're looking to `reindex`: `df2.reindex(['z', 'x', 'y'], axis=1)`

Comment: Thanks @ALollz. I need `df1` because it is not always empty. It depends on the user's input.

Answer (score 1):

The following command:

```
    df2.merge(df1, on=['x', 'y'], how='outer')
```

produces

```
   x  y    z
0  1  2  NaN
```

The index is not the one you need, so you can do this instead:

```
    df2.reset_index().merge(df1, on=['x', 'y'], how='outer').set_index('index')
```

producing

```
       x  y    z
index           
foo    1  2  NaN
```

If you want to remove the word 'index', name the above dataframe `df3` and:

```
    del df3.index.name
```

resulting in

```
     x  y    z
foo  1  2  NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't just:

```
df2['z'] = df1['z']
```